# VBA Macro to Sort a Column but add a value to the original value if there are duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that currently automatically sorts one of my columns into ascending order as I input the values, this is so that I can sort out a number of tasks into a priority order. This is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("E2").Sort Key1:=Range("E3"), _
          Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

However, what I want to know is if there's a way so that say if I declare one task to the value of 1, and then another task to the value of 1, it changes the original value to 2 so that I have no duplicate values and a clear order of the tasks.

I have looked at multiple if statements or just regular formulas however I can't work out how to complete this second part.

Thanks

ADDED -

Sorry I may not have explained it as best I could have. Here it is as a diagram to make it easier to understand:

```
Task    Priority
Task 1  1
Task 2  2
Task 3  3
Task 4  4
Task 5  5
Task 6  6
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
Task    Priority
Task 6  1
Task 1  2
Task 2  3
Task 3  4
Task 4  5
Task 5  6
```

So basically, If I set Task 6 to priority 1, this will move all the other tasks down a priority.

Sorry, I found it very hard to explain as I am new to VBA.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want that? This produces a chain reaction, imagine you have already 1, 2, 3, 4 and then you add another 1 that makes the original 1 a 2 and the original 2 a 3 and so on. This will take more time if the list gets longer.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what id like to happen, I would want all numbers to be moved down.

Comment: I would create a UDF. Then once you get into your `IF` statement, call this UDF before the sort. Import your range into an array, change the values in the array and then transpose the values back into your sheet. You can then run the `Sort` on the range. As far as I know, this will the fastest way of doing what you want

Comment: How is resorting the data not making the worksheeet_change run on top of itself?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question .. You want to control the value of the active cell when you are entering a value; if this value does not already exist in your column; and if it exists; that its value must be incremented by 1.
If it's your case, I have a solution:
You use the SelectionChange event of your spreadsheet with a control on the ActiveCell.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     Set myrange = Sheets("MyCurrentWorksheet").Range("C2:C100")  'Or set myrange = .range("C:C") If Entire Column
     If Application.CountIf(myrange, ActiveCell.Value) > 1 Then ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1
 End Sub
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I may have not explained very well, I have added diagrams to hopefully make it easier. Thanks for the submission though! :)